# Send emails from tvOs app

Tags: swift, email, tvos, messageui

I am developing a tvOs application, using Swift 2.0, and i want it to send an email each time the app crashes, as a crash report. I tried implementing the MessageUI framework, but is not available for tvOs anymore. Does anybody knows what other framework or technology available for tvOs i could use instead in order to send emails from my tv app? Cheers!

Comment: Don't do that, you'll regret it very fast if you have many users. Use a tool like Crashlytics instead (just an example, there's many others).

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's a much more elegant and efficient solution.